# Facing issue while trying to run the updateitem in dynamo db

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am able to fetch the record from dynamo db and view the response successfully. I need to modify the fetched '**ACCOUNTNAME**' attribute in the '**items**' **array** and update the json and also update in dynamo db. Now when I try to update the fetched records I end up with the **Invalid attribute value type** exception.

I was trying to update it using the key with Array of Strings which is provided with code snippet also tried to update inside for loop using the individual string but both failed with same exception as

```
  "statusCode": 400,
  "body": {
    "message": "Invalid attribute value type",
    "error": {
      "errorMessage": "ValidationException"
    }
  }
```

I tried to create params and update the call inside the for loop by setting the key as below,

```
      Key: {
       "UUID": {
            "S": usersOfAccountFromDB.body.Items[key].UUID
        }
        ,
       "TYPE": {
            "S": user
        }  
      }
```

but also failed with the same exception.

Fetched Json from dynamo db

```
[
  {
    "DEFINITION": "914ba44a-8c26-4b60-af0f-96b6aa37efe6",
    "UUID": "830a49cb-4ed3-41ae-b111-56714a71ab98",
    "TYPE": "USER",
    "RELATION": "01efd131-6a5d-4068-889e-9dba44262da5",
    "ACCOUNTNAME": "Wolff LLC"
  },
  {
    "DEFINITION": "1f60fded-323d-40e1-a7f8-e2d053b0bed0",
    "UUID": "47db3bbe-53ac-4e58-a378-f42331141997",
    "TYPE": "USER",
    "RELATION": "01efd131-6a5d-4068-889e-9dba44262da5",
    "ACCOUNTNAME": "Wolff LLC"
  },
  {
    "DEFINITION": "05ddccba-2b6d-46bd-9db4-7b897ebe16ca",
    "UUID": "e7290457-db77-48fc-bd1a-7056bfce8fab",
    "TYPE": "USER",
    "RELATION": "01efd131-6a5d-4068-889e-9dba44262da5",
    "ACCOUNTNAME": "Wolff LLC"
  },
.
.
.
.]
```

Now I tried to iterate the Json and setup UUID which is the key as the String array as below,

```
    var userUUIDArray : string[] = [];
    for (let key in usersOfAccountFromDB.body.Items) {
      userUUIDArray.push(usersOfAccountFromDB.body.Items[key].UUID);
    }

    for (var uuid of userUUIDArray) {
    console.log("UUID : " +uuid);     // prints all the uuid
    }

    // Creating a parameter for the update dynamo db
    var params = {
    TableName: <tableName>,
    Key: {
      "UUID": {
            "SS": userUUIDArray
        }
        ,
      "TYPE": {
            "S": user
        }  
    },               
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #ACCOUNTNAME = :val1',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#ACCOUNTNAME': 'ACCOUNTNAME'       //COLUMN NAME   
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':val1': newAccountName  
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    };

    //call the update of dynamodb
    const result = await this.getDocClient().update(param).promise();
```

I get the error as below,

```
    "body": {
    "message": "Invalid attribute value type",
    "error": {
      "errorMessage": "ValidationException"
      }
    }
```

All the approaches failed with same above exception

Answer (score 0):

The `update` operation which your code currently uses only allow a single item to be updated.

IIUC, you want to update multiple items with one API call. For this you need to use [`batchWrite`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property) operation. Keep in mind that you cannot update more than 25 items per invocation.

### The origin of the error you are getting

Your code fails due to the use of `"SS"` in the `UUID` field. This field is of type string so you must use `"S"`. Note however that since you're using the document client API you *do not* need to pass values using this notation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804745/difference-between-aws-sdk-dynamodb-client-and-documentclient/57807642#57807642) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I tried to hard code the value instead of String Array to string but still face the similar issue .  ```     Key: {
      UUID: {
            S: "830a49cb-4ed3-41ae-b111-56714a71ab98"
        },
        TYPE: {
            S: "USER"
        }
    }  ```

Comment: What is the value of `newAccountName`?

Comment: This is a value that needs to be updated to the dynamo db attribute name 'ACCOUNTNAME'

Comment: I understand. what is its value? is it a number? a string? something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue now by running the update statement one by one using loop

```
for (let key in usersOfAccountFromDB.body.Items) {

  var updateParam = {
    TableName: process.env.AWS_DYNAMO_TABLE,
    Key: {
      UUID: usersOfAccountFromDB.body.Items[key].UUID,      
      TYPE: user 
    },     
    UpdateExpression: "SET #ACCOUNTNAME = :val1",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#ACCOUNTNAME': 'ACCOUNTNAME'   
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":val1": newAccountName
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
  };

  const result = await this.getDocClient().update(updateParam).promise();                   
}
```